# konjunktiv 1, first person singular perfect, should I use konjunkiv 2?

Tags: subjunctive

I have read that if konjunktiv 1 is similar to Indicative mode, then use konjunktiv 2. Imagine verb Melden, in konunktiv 1 of it, first person singular, first person plural and third person plural , are similar to indicative mode. so I should use konjunktiv2 ?

for example:

> "Zeitung berichtet, ich hätte es gemalt"

is this sentence correct?

Comment: This looks like a homework question. Proof reading is discouraged on here.

Answer (score 1):

> Zeitung berichtet, ich hätte es gemalt

means

> newspaper announces I've painted it

But you want to use **Melden** (announce)

So I'd write:

`"Zeitung X berichtet, die Person Y meldete ABC"` (if X assumes a proof of what Y said)

or

`"Zeitung X berichtet, die Person Y hat angeblich ABC gemeldet"` (if X does not approve of what Y said)

which is equivalent to:

`"Zeitung X berichtet, die Person Y haette ABC gemeldet"`

Comment: thanks but what about general idea?  in konunktiv 1 , first person singular, first person plural and third person plural , are similar to indicative mode. so I should use konjunktiv 2 ?

Comment: I'm a native speaker and my answer reflects what I'd use in this case... I'm not so sure about the linguistic rules... AND it will change from case to case, from phrase to phrase, from meaning to meaning!